Парсинг Habr (Python + LxmlSoup)
Только начал пробовать в парсинг, решил сделать бота, который присылает список статей.
Тут я собираю заголовки и ссылки на последние статьи:
from LxmlSoup import LxmlSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://habr.com/ru/articles/').text
soup = LxmlSoup(html)

links = soup.find_all('a', class_='tm-title__link')

for i, link in enumerate(links, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {link.text()}')
    print('https://habr.com' + link.get('href'), '\n')

Теперь вопросы:

Как ограничить парсинг до 3-5 результатов? Чтобы он не всю страничку собирал, а только новые 3-5 статей (они на хабре упорядочены).
Как получить время публикации статьи? Рядом с заголовком на хабре пишется "55 минут назад", хочу записывать конкретное время (чтобы собрать статистику, типа "В четверг среднее время публикации статьи - 40 минут")
Где и ЧТО почитать про html - с трудом понимаю какие теги надо искать и как из них доставать информацию.

Если что задачи несут исключительно учебный характер.


В LxmlSoup параметра limit для функции find_all(), как я понял, нет, в отличие от его прародителя, BeautifulSoup. Так что стоит либо перейти на bs4:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://habr.com/ru/articles/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

articles_limit = 5  # Изменить число статей на любое душе угодное
links = soup.find_all('a', class_='tm-title__link', limit=articles_limit)

for i, link in enumerate(links, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {link.text}')
    print('https://habr.com' + link.get('href'), '\n')

либо парсить все статьи с помощью LxmlSoup, а потом вывести лишь первые пять ссылок (если лишние статьи вам и для хранения в списке не нужны, можно воспользоваться срезкой):
...
articles_limit = 5
for i, link in enumerate(links[:articles_limit], start=1):
    ...


Хабр не просто так помещает дату публикации в тег <time> с соответствующими ему атрибутами:

<time datetime="2024-08-24T12:36:58.000Z" title="2024-08-24, 20:36">18 минут назад</time>

Можно вытянуть оттуда дату через атрибут либо datetime, либо title, смотря, с каким форматом вам проще работать:
# В качестве примера взял код с bs4 выше
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://habr.com/ru/articles/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

articles_count = 5
articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='tm-articles-list__item', limit=articles_count)

for i, article in enumerate(articles, start=1):
    link = article.find('a', class_='tm-title__link')
    date = article.find('a', class_='tm-article-datetime-published').find('time')
    print(f'{i}: {link.text}')
    print('https://habr.com' + link.get('href'))
    article_datetime = date.get('datetime')  # Либо date.get('title')
    print(f'Время публикации: {article_datetime}', '\n')


Если вы впринципе хотите почитать про то, какие есть элементы и для чего они нужны, рекомендую документацию MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/) на английском (можно на русском, но переведено и перенесено не всё) или https://doka.guide/html/ на русском.
Если вам нужно разобраться только с семантикой Хабра, открывайте DevTools и исследуйте всё, что вас интересует.


Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ

Первый вопрос:

"Как ограничить парсинг до 3-5 результатов?"

magic_numbers = (13, 42, 54, 32, 12, 144)

for i, item in enumerate(magic_numbers, 1):
    if i > 5:
        print('Больше 5-ти элементов нам не надо, прерываем цикл.')
        break

    print(''.join(('Обработали:\n- первый элемент'.__mul__(i==1),
                   '- второй элемент'.__mul__(i==2),
                   '- третий элемент'.__mul__(i==3),
                   '- четвёртый элемент'.__mul__(i==4),
                   '- пятый элемент'.__mul__(i==5),)
                  )
    )

output:
Обработали:     
- первый элемент
- второй элемент
- третий элемент
- четвёртый элемент
- пятый элемент
"Больше 5-ти элементов нам не надо, прерываем цикл."

Второй и третий вопрос:

В браузере выделяете мышкой нужный контент и ПКМ вызываешь контекстное меню:

(может быть пункт: "исследовать элемент" - это зависит от браузера)
Дальше смотришь в каком теге нужные данные и смотришь родительские теги,
чтоб понять как выдернуть нужный контент.



Интересный способ добавления if-else к однотипным строкам. Но можно было обойтись и без непонятного magic_numbers

@Mipsirint magic_numbers перекочевал из другого ответа, там сочетание магического метода с магическими числами выглядит более органично. ;)

А тут оно выглядит как дичь

@eri Ну, Вы то должны понимать, что это просто последовательность! Как и этот список – links = soup.find_all('a', class_='tm-title__link')

@AnnaBazueva по первому вопросу: я так понимаю, тут мы делаем условный срез уже по результату. Я бы хотел узнать как парсить определенное количество строк

@Irking Да, цель достигнута - голову включили! ;)  Если бы написала for item in magic_numbers[:5] - этого могло не произойти. Ну или можете использовать bs4, как Вам рекомендовал @Mipsirint . Успехов!

@Irking На requests.get() Вы получаете весь доступный html страницы, и уже в нём выбираете нужные элементы (для удобства получаете список методом soup.find_all()) – понимаете?

@Irking Ну, можно найти первый элемент методом soup.find() и отталкиваясь от него искать следующий... Но для чего так делать !?

@AnnaBazueva "Вы получаете весь доступный html страницы, и уже в нём выбираете нужные элементы", да, Вы правы на 100%. Об этом я не подумал.
